# Confluence - Minimizing emails on updates - show diff from earlier save

Tags: confluence

My company's inbox is inundated with emails from Confluence. Users don't want their edits lost, so they save their work frequently (with the "Notify watchers" option checked. Assuming I can get them to uncheck the notify option until they are happy with all their changes...

It would be ideal if Confluence would email the difference from the last time "Notify users" was selected or the last time a comment was entered in "What did you change"

This would eliminate hundreds of users the need to delete hundreds of superfluous emails ever day but insure that they do receive important change notifications.

Comment: FWIW: The default Confluence settings are insane - IMHO. 

I have one client who simply dumped Confluence. Another was willing to do the work to "dial back" the settings to something more reasonable. I no longer recommend Confluence - unless the organization is already invested in the "ecosystem".

Edit: Of course this is but one of several issues :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following free plugin, which adds a separate "Save and notify" button to the editor, which reduces the notifications considerably since users don't have to explicitly uncheck the notification box.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/confluence.extra.noemailstorm

Newer versions of Confluence also batch several updates into one email, though from my experience, this still doesn't properly prevent the notification spam.